# Delete All VBA code on the sheet before sending it via e-mail

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that extracts only the active sheet and send it to specific email.
I have a 6 CommandButtons on that sheet which are attached to some codes.
So I need to implement some code in this(sending)code to delete all CB-s and all code in it, before sendin it. It would shrink sending file a lot.

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
'Working in Excel 2000-2013
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm

    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim Sourcewb As Workbook
    Dim Destwb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim x As Integer


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
            'You use Excel 2007-2013
            Select Case Sourcewb.FileFormat
            Case 51: FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
            Case 52:
                If .HasVBProject Then
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsm": FileFormatNum = 52
                Else
                    FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
                End If
            Case 56: FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = 56
            Case Else: FileExtStr = ".xlsb": FileFormatNum = 50
            End Select
        End If
    End With

    '    'Change all cells in the worksheet to values if you want
    '   With Destwb.Sheets(1).UsedRange
    '       .Cells.Copy
    '       .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    '       .Cells(1).Select
    '   End With
    '   Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'Save the new workbook/Mail it/Delete it
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Pregled " & Sourcewb.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With Destwb
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1").Delete  'this only deletes the CB-s
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton2").Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton3").Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton4").Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton5").Delete
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton6").Delete



        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .To = "exemple@email.ba"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "Izvještaj za kutije"
            .Body = "Izvještaj u prilogu! LP."
            .Attachments.Add Destwb.FullName
            'You can add other files also like this
            '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
            .Send   'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your file (using a macro if you wish so) as .xlsx file instead of .xlsm .

Say you want to save Sheet1, Sheet2:

```
Sub SaveAsXSLX()
    Worksheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:="NewFileName.xlsx"
end sub
```

This method shall prevent alert message popping (error message like "can not save this format to non macro format).

Comment: Ok so give me a solution practicaly, rewrite part of the code that saves it in xlsm format.

Comment: Can you implement that in my code, mybe in this line:
 .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum